# How to execute a trigger from PL/SQL before inserting a row on a table with Entity Framework database-first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, plsql

I have created a trigger in PL/SQL that is triggered when before inserting a row in the table, this through an Oracle sequence increases the value, then inserts into the table as primary key.

This is my trigger code from PL/SQL:

```
create or replace trigger FUT_SYS_USER_BE_I
before insert on FUT_SYS_USER referencing old as O new as N
for each row
  declare
  --local variables here
  begin
    if :N.SYS_USER_ID is null then
      :N.SYS_USER_ID := SYS_USER_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    end if;
  end FUT_SYS_USER_BE_I;
```

But this trigger is never executed since when I insert a row the primary key `SYS_USER_ID` never increases and saves the value of zero.

This is my code from C#:

```
using(DemoDBEntities db = new DemoDBEntities())
{
        FUT_SYS_USER SU = new FUT_SYS_USER();
        SU.LOGIN_NAME = user.LoginName;
        SU.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED_TEXT = user.Password;
        SU.ROW_CREATED_SYSUSER_ID = user.SYSUserID > 0 ? user.SYSUserID : 1;
        SU.ROW_MODIFIED_SYSUSER_ID = user.SYSUserID > 0 ? user.SYSUserID : 1; 
        SU.ROW_CREATED_DATETIME = DateTime.Now;
        SU.ROW_MODIFIED_DATETIME = DateTime.Now;

        db.FUT_SYS_USER.Add(SU);
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any ideas of how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with oracle, but doesn't it have an auto increment feature for it's primary key?

Comment: My guess is that `SYS_USER_ID` is filled by the entity framework to 0 at which point the value is not null anymore and the trigger passes setting the `SYS_USER_ID` to the value of the sequence. Check whether you can pass `SYS_USER_ID` explicitly as `NULL` of change the logic of your `IF` statement in your trigger. And yes, @Kurev, Oracle provides an Identity column, i.e. auto increment feature since 12.1.0.1

Comment: You have to create a sequence first and then with SYS_USER_SEQ.NEXTVAL increments the value.

Comment: Prior to Oracle 12.1 you can code it in a row-level trigger as in the example, which looks fine, except that allowing for two different key sequences in the same PK is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell EF that this is a column that's being filled by the database. If you have your `.edmx` designer open, select that column in question, and look at its properties. What you're looking for is the property **StoreGeneratedPattern**, which can be set to "None" (the default), or "Computed" or "Identity".

I'm not sure which one will work in Oracle, but in SQL Server, for the `identity` columns (that get auto-incremented automatically by SQL Server when inserting a row), I always set the `StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity` - in this case, EF won't send a value to the database for this column, and then your trigger should do its work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **StoreGeneratedPattern** to Identity for the key column(SYS_USER_ID) in the `.edmx` model properties for that column. If in future if you delete the table from `.edmx` model and recreate you need to set this again.